# Solution to 99 lisp problems, p09 in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am *fairly* new to ruby, and I am worried that my solution to problem 9 of the 99 lisp problems is **extremly** convoluted and inefficient. 
The problem is:

[image]

My Code

```
ul = "putanytexthere"
h = []

ul.upcase
  .split('')
  .sort
  .join('')
  .each_char
  .slice_when { |a,b| a != b }
  .map(&:join)
  .each do |el|
    if el.length > 1
      h << el
    end
  end

  print h.length
```

Comment: Could you add a test case or two?

Comment: Does your code give the expected output for the input in the exercise? I would start by verifying that before you try and simplify your code.

Comment: The output of your code does not match the expected output for the given example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a couple code style things:

- Logic like this is best encapsulated in a method
- Long method chains like this are best broken down into logical parts, for better readability.

So, I'll go step by step here with changes to your code. First, encapsulate it in a method:

```
def pack_duplicates(ul)
  h = []

  ul.upcase
    .split('')
    .sort
    .join('')
    .each_char
    .slice_when { |a,b| a != b }
    .map(&:join)
    .each do |el|
      if el.length > 1
        h << el
      end
    end

  return h
end

puts pack_duplicates("putanytexthere").length
```

Then, break that long chain into logical parts:

```
def pack_duplicates(ul)
  h = []

  chars = ul.upcase.split('').sort
  # You called #join on this and #each_char, but #each_char
  # basically just undoes #join, so we can eliminate both.
  groups = chars.slice_when { |a,b| a != b }.map(&:join)
  groups.each do |el|
    if el.length > 1
      h << el
    end
  end

  return h
end

puts pack_duplicates("putanytexthere").length
```

And finally, when you see an each loop that builds an array, that typically means that the `#each` can be replaced with `#map`:

```
def pack_duplicates(ul)    
  chars = ul.upcase.split('').sort
  groups = chars.slice_when { |a, b| a != b }.map(&:join)
  final = groups.map do |el|
    [el[0], el.length] 
  end.to_h
end

puts pack_duplicates("putanystringhere")
```

In the `#map` call above, I made some changes to your original output. Instead of generating an array, I generated a hash with the format `{<char> => <number of occurances>}`. This makes more logical sense to me than your output. (To get your output, you can call `pack_duplicates("somestr").count { |_char, count| count > 1 }`)

In addition, your code outputs a number -- the length of the output array, while the challenge mandates what appears to be a nested array. This nested array is output by the `#slice_when` line, so I don't quite understand what comes after that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that aims to solve the described problem.

**Note** that your initial solutions is doing more that the problem requires, you are handling string instead of lists, are ordering them, and the output isn't the one desired by the problem.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class L99
  # P09 (**) Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists.
  # If a list contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.
  def self.pack(list)
    list.slice_when { |i, j| i != j }.to_a
  end
end

class PackTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_pack
    list = %i[a a a a b c c a a d e e e e]
    expected = [%i[a a a a], [:b], %i[c c], %i[a a], [:d], %i[e e e e]]

    assert_equal expected, L99.pack(list)
  end

  def test_pack_string
    str = 'putanytexthere'
    expected = [['a'], %w[e e e], ['h'], ['n'], ['p'], ['r'], %w[t t t], ['u'], ['x'], ['y']]


    assert_equal expected, L99.pack(str.each_char.sort)
  end
end
```